# Android How to catch end of incoming/outgoing call with number?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I found some articles which describes how to get outgoing and incoming call number. But all of these articles are executed in time when phone start ringing but not after the end of the incoming/outgoing call.

Could somebody tell me how can i do this in Android?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` on TelephonyManager to detect whether a call has ended or not.

```
if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Detected Call Hangup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```